# Does the .net framework 3.0 bootstrapper include the .net framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I have an application that uses .net Framework 3.0 as its target framework.
When creating the setup and deployment project for my app, i am including in the prerequisites the .net framework 2.0 bootstrapper and the .net framework 3.0 bootstrapper.

Will it be enough to include just the 3.0 boootstrapper and ignore and exclude the 2.0 bootstrapper?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should be enough  to install 3.0

Both Fx 3.0 and Fx 3.5 are extended version of Fx 2.0 (ie they run on the CLR 2.0)

Comment: My setup package also contains the "Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies". After i removed the 2.0 bootstrapper, the PIA are throwing an error when installing: [The Microsoft .NET Framework version 1.1.4322 or later must be installed before this package can be installed". Any idea?

Comment: No, not a clue. Carefully check if you have other interop versions available (and clean/rebuild all generated stuff).

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i change the order of the prerequisites installation? (i want to let 3.0 install before the PIA and not after)

Comment: I would hope the installer is smart enough to do that. Do you think that is the problem? You seem to need Fx 1.1